# Sinatra accept header option value

Tags: sinatra, rack

Given this accept header:

```
application/vnd.example.api.json; version=42
```

Is there a simple way to fetch the value of `version`, without parsing `env['HTTP_ACCEPT']`?

**BTW:**

Inspecting `request.accept`, we can found a `@params` instance method:

```
[#<Sinatra::Request::AcceptEntry:0x007fd214b3e500 @entry="application/vnd.example.api.json; version=42", @type="application/vnd.example.api.json", @params={"version"=>"42"}, @q=1.0>]
```

They may be a way to access it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer should be: YES

Long answer: go here: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L74
look at the code:

```
class AcceptEntry
  attr_accessor :params
  [...]
end
```

So this should boil down to:

```
request.accept[0].params['version'] #=> 42
```

Comment: Strange, I've got: `NoMethodError - undefined method 'params' for #<Array:0x007fcc12319bc0>`...

Comment: @Doug `request.accept` returns an array of `AcceptEntry`s. You’ll need something like `request.accept.find { |entry| entry.to_s == 'application/vnd.example.api.json'}.params['version']`. (You should also check to see if the result of `find` is `nil` as well.)

Comment: Just fixed the answer, witch seems to be the simplest solution.